# Installation of VCP (VirtualCOM) Driver

Tags: drivers

I want to install a VCP(VirtuaCOM) Port Driver. I downloaded the driver form http://www.ftdichip.com/Drivers/VCP.htm and extracted the folder.
In this folder there is a Makefile, a Rules.make, a ftdi_sio.c and a ftdi_sio.h.
I read in some other blogs to execute the
./configure
enter the command
make
sudo make install
but there is no configure file and when I do the make command I get an error.

Answer (score 1):

Look [here](http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/AppNotes/AN_220_FTDI_Drivers_Installation_Guide_for_Linux%20.pdf) but according to the link you put, all FTDI devices are supported in Ubuntu 11.10 and forward, and for custom VCPs check [here](http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/TechnicalNotes/TN_101_Customising_FTDI_VID_PID_In_Linux%28FT_000081%29.pdf).